# Silverlight XAML arcsegment size animation

Tags: silverlight, animation

I'm using Silverlight 4, trying to animate an arcsegment's size property.  The only type of animation I've had success with is ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.  This turns out to be a pain, so I've tried doing a double animation on the height and width of the size property but that doesn't work.

```
   <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="20">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,200">
                    <ArcSegment x:Name="ArcSeg1" Size="100,100" RotationAngle="0" IsLargeArc="True" 
                        SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="200,200" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>

    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="ArcSeg1"
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Size.Width"
         From="100"
         To="50"
         Duration="00:00:05"
     />
```

But this only results in the following error:

Cannot resolve TargetProperty Size.Width on specified object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Size is a DependencyProperty (and hence u can animate it), Size.Width is not. (Width is just a regular property)

Try and animate the Path itself.